# An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I recently work with elasticsearch and I've got a problem. I have 9million object in index. And when I am trying to get a lot of them from index I've got the next exception:

```
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:276)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:245)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:223)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:358)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.SessionInputBufferImpl.fill(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:231)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.AbstractMessageParser.fillBuffer(AbstractMessageParser.java:136)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:241)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

After that my local elastic just closed.
Here is my client configuration:

```
@Data
@Configuration
public class ElasticConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private ElasticProperties elasticProperties;

    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient buildClient() {
        final HttpHost host = getHttpHost();
        return new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(host).setRequestConfigCallback(builder -> builder.setConnectTimeout(5000).setSocketTimeout(1000000)));
    }

    private HttpHost getHttpHost() {
        return new HttpHost(elasticProperties.getHostname(), elasticProperties.getPort(), elasticProperties.getScheme());
    }
}
```

Why is it happens and how it can be fixed?

Comment: if you need to grab X millions or records at once, you are not using Elasticsearch correctly

Comment: @DejanMarić I am doing this through scroll. I can share my implementation if it can help to solve the problem

Comment: it's not necessary if you use scroll, do you have load balancer / firewall or something that might block the connection. How much RAM you have and what is heap on Elasticsearch in .yml ?

Comment: @DejanMarić 16RAM and it was 1gb in my jvm.options.When I changed to 8gb and now I've got the next error 'entity content is too long [1397118555] for the configured buffer limit [104857600]' Maybe is it possible to get data in parts using scroll?

Comment: well, looks like your issue was heap related. Yes, this error is indicating that you want more then 10 000 docs at once, use scroll or "from-size" query to fetch chunks

Comment: @DejanMarić I've got this when using scroll)

Comment: glad I could help